# Change Actionbar color and its text alignment When navigating to next activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

I am want to change the color of ActionBar in my Android app.

If I click on the button to go to the next activity, I want to change Actionbar color too, but it shows "Unfortunately, app has stopped".

Below is my code, let me know if anything wrong in it..?

My Code:

Manifests code:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_152"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <activity
        android:name=".WelcomeScreen"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignIn"
        android:label="Sign In"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
        android:parentActivityName=".WelcomeScreen"></activity>
</application>
```

values/theme.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleBarTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:background">#3366CC</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/backarrow_white</item>
</style>
<style name="TitleBarTextColor"     parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

values/styles.xml code:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practices is to use Toolbar : [See this android developers page](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html).

Using Toolbar, you can set up the layout you want to use and change background color and text alignment.

Comment: Thanks man. I have to design custom toolbar for back button, center text and color of text. Right?

Comment: You can customize the layout as you want ( text gravity, color...). The back button is set up using 
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
</style>
```

Comment: actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000"))); try this

Comment: Can you please copy your log cat .

Answer (score 0):

you not show your java code where this error is start but try this one

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#95CDBA")));
        actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000099'>Hello World</font>"));
```

and imports

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```